# PDF ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiscrollview

My PDF scroll view (copied from [Apple’s ZoomingPDFViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) example, but modified a bit) can’t seem to zoom, although it’s displaying the data.

Here is what Apple uses in the example to add it:

```
CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
[(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];
```

And because that second line gave me errors, I changed it to this:

```
CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
PDFScrollView *sv = [[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[sv setPDFPage:PDFPage];
self.view = sv;
```

But now I can’t seem to zoom the PDF.

The Apple one works well without errors, but if I use this line in my app, I get the following error when that view loads:

```
-[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5b10b0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5b10b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3424c2a3 0x33a1e97f 0x3424fe07 0x3424e531 0x341a5f68 0x8c499 0x36da3595 0x36df813b 0x36df8081 0x36df7f65 0x36df7e89 0x36df75c9 0x36df74b1 0x36de5b93 0x36de5833 0x79acd 0x36e46275 0x36ec8ea9 0x39249a6f 0x342215df 0x34221291 0x3421ff01 0x34192ebd 0x34192d49 0x34efb2eb 0x36dd8301 0x6e601 0x38e17b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

The only other difference in my setup is that the view controller where this is called is inside a navigation controller, which is inside of a tab bar controller. But I can’t see how this would affect the problem.

Any tips?

#### [UPDATE]

This is my custom init method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.scrollEnabled = true;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It is the same as `initWithCoder` except that I added `self.scrollEnabled = true;`.

I also tried these, and it still didn’t work:

```
//UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
PDFScrollView *sv = [[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.view = sv;
[(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage];
```

When I use the commented-out line (UIScrollView), it gives me the same error, except that it says `[UIScrollView setPDFPage:]: unrecognized...`. When I use the uncommented line (PDFScrollView), it gives me no error and shows the PDF, but there’s still no zooming.

Comment: I had the exact same problem a few weeks ago. I'm not at my computer right now, but try the following. In your XIB file, your view controller's view has to be a UIScrollView, not a UIView. Once you change this and link the scroll view to self.view, Apple's code should work.

Comment: @JackHumphries thanks for the tip, but I am not working with any XIB's .

Comment: @JackHumphries AH! thats the problem! Thanks a lot! haha

Comment: @JackHumphries Yup! Say your solution and also something about checking the XIB's connections.

Comment: @Nat, thanks for helping with the grammar - I do speak English as a second language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view` must be a scroll view in order to be cast as a `PDFScrollView` and accept its methods. By default, `self.view` is a UIView. Either change the view to a scroll view in your XIB file (delete the view and link the scroll view to `view` in File's Owner) or do it programmatically.